# swift ui アラート 'navigationBarLeading' is unavailable in macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

swift ui でバーアイテムを追加しようとすると以下のアラートが出ます。

```
'navigationBarLeading' is unavailable in macOS
```

アップデートかと思い、アップデートしたのですが解消されません。
バーアイテムは違う表記になったのですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOSでは`navigationBarLeading`がサポートされていません。
ただの`navigaiton`とかを使いましょう

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemplacement

Comment: ありがとうございます。